# nlme fit : vcov versus summary

Tags: r, nlme

I have fitted a model using `nlme()` from the `package nlme`.

Now I wish to simulate some prediction intervals, taking into account parameter uncertainty.

To this end, I need to extract the variance matrix for the fixed effects.

As far as I am aware, there are two ways of doing this:

```
vcov(fit)
```

and

```
summary(fit)$varFix
```

These two give the same matrix.

However, if I inspect

```
diag(vcov(fit))^.5
```

it is NOT the same as the reported Std Error in `summary(fit)`

Am I wrong to expect these two to be the same?

Edit: Here is a code example

```
require(nlme)

f=expression(exp(-a*t))
a=c(.5,1.5)
pts=seq(0,4,by=.1)

sim1=function(t) eval(f,list(a=a[1],t))+rnorm(1)*.1
y1=sapply(pts,sim1)

sim2=function(t) eval(f,list(a=a[2],t))+rnorm(1)*.1
y2=sapply(pts,sim2)

y=c(y1,y2)
t=c(pts,pts)
batch=factor(rep(1:2,82))
d=data.frame(t,y,batch)

nlmeFit=nlme(y~exp(-a*t),
  fixed=a~1,
  random=a~1|batch,
  start=c(a=1),
  data=d
  )

vcov(nlmeFit)
summary(nlmeFit)$varFix
vcov(nlmeFit)^.5
summary(nlmeFit)
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide your dataset, or at least a representative sample, and show the code you used to get the fit.

Comment: I agree. But the data set is not mine and I reasoned that anyone likely to be able to answer would have used nlme in the past and therefore have nlme fits readily available. Since I am pointing out an issue that should be data independent in general, I had hoped it would not become an issue. That is, if people cannot confirm non-equality of the two matrices in their own examples that would be a pretty big hint that I am doing something wrong.

But I can go away and simulate a data set if you think that will help.

Comment: Yes, demonstrating the problem with data you can post is important.

Comment: Have edited the post to simulate data. Every time you run the code block you get different answers for the two standard deviation / standard error estimates.

Comment: This is easier to reproduce: `library(nlme); example(nlme); all.equal(sqrt(diag(vcov(fm2))),summary(fm2)$tTable[,"Std.Error"])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a bias correction term; it's documented in `?summary.lme`.

> adjustSigma: an optional logical value. If ‘TRUE’ and the estimation
>             method used to obtain ‘object’ was maximum likelihood, the
>             residual standard error is multiplied by sqrt(nobs/(nobs -
>             npar)), converting it to a REML-like estimate. This argument
>             is only used when a single fitted object is passed to the
>             function. Default is ‘TRUE’.

If you look inside `nlme:::summary.lme` (which is the method used to generate the summary of an `nlme` object as well, since it has class `c("nlme", "lme")`), you see:

```
...
stdFixed <- sqrt(diag(as.matrix(object$varFix)))
...
if (adjustSigma && object$method == "ML") 
    stdFixed <- stdFixed * sqrt(object$dims$N/(object$dims$N - 
        length(stdFixed)))
```

That is, the standard error is being scaled by `sqrt(n/(n-p))` where `n` is the number of observations and `p` the number of fixed-effect parameters. Let's check this out:

```
 library(nlme)
 fm1 <- nlme(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
             data = Loblolly,
             fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
             random = Asym ~ 1,
             start = c(Asym = 103, R0 = -8.5, lrc = -3.3))
 summary(fm1)$tTable[,"Std.Error"]
 ##       Asym         R0        lrc 
 ## 2.46169512 0.31795045 0.03427017 

 nrow(Loblolly) ## 84
 sqrt(diag(vcov(fm1)))*sqrt(84/(84-3))
 ##      Asym         R0        lrc 
 ## 2.46169512 0.31795045 0.03427017
```

I have to admit that I found the answer in the code and only then looked back to see that it was perfectly clearly stated in the documentation ...

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot - I never thought to look in the summary documentation. And perhaps I am guilty of laziness in not looking in the code. I believe I have accepted and upvoted your answer.